# Changing button color on state changed angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have grey color button and i need to implement it with 2 states one for selected (blue)and other for idle state(grey). I am working on Angularjs. I am new to this platform.

Please provide tutorial or sample code with output.

Comment: In javascript we can take reference to the button and change the background. How do we do it in ANGULARJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably give a class that you can add to your button, say "selected". Next would be flipping a variable for when this btn is selected:

```
$scope.isSelected = true;
```

Now use `ng-class on the button:

```
<button ng-class="{'selected':isSelected}"></button>
```

Basically, when `isSelected` is true, add class `selected`.

**EDIT:** Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KgShW/1/) conveying this implementation

Comment: Was in the process of creating an answer w/ fiddle, here is fiddle which would match this answer... http://jsfiddle.net/KgShW/1/

Comment: @Brocco your answer made things simpler if you would have posted as answer instead of comment i would have selected it as answer. Anyways Thanks a ton for fiddle :)

Comment: @NiranjanBalkrishnaPrajapati I appreciate that, but in reality they are the same answer just in different forms. And because his answer was submitted after I created the fiddle it was appropriate to place it here.